# Handling component errors with ngrx

Tags: angular, error-handling, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

*Let's presume I have the following scenario:*

- Open List component
- Dispatch new LoadList() that updates the store with a list of data
- Subscribe to list state and display list
- On list row click open Details component (which is displayed next to the list)
- Dispatch new LoadDetails() that updates same store list with an item
- Subscribe to details and display item info

**That works as expected.**

*Now presume the following scenario:*

- Open List component
- Dispatch new LoadList() that updates the store with a list of data
- Subscribe to list state and display list
- On list row click open Details component (which is displayed next to the list)
- Dispatch new LoadDetails() **that fails with some error**
- **Subscribe to details and display Error dialog only on details component (list should stay intact)**

And this is just a basic example. What if I have multiple components visible at the same time, taking the data from the same store ... 
ex. Some registry store that holds the list of items where some are required on one component, few on the other component + maybe only updating the item fails which is again its own component visible at the same time ...

**Is there some elegant way of handling this kind of errors?**

P.S.: I can achieve that with some Map that can hold error for each item and action but this doesn't sound right + too much boilerplate ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be using the same data objects in multiple places. I like to store them in state by a unique id as a map. Then have another store data structure that stores the groups of the item id's. This is often how I store paged sets of objects.

When you get your data back from API/DB etc, store it in two places in the Store.

for example:

```
// Store
personPages$: {
    1: {
        meta: {pageSize: 3, totalItems: 6},
        results: [1, 2, 4]
    },
    2: {
        meta: {pageSize: 3, totalItems: 6},
        results: [7, 3, 8]
    }
}
...
personEntities$: {
    1: {
        name: Han Solo, age: 37, weapon: blaster 
    },
    2: { 
       name: Luke Skywalker, age: 22, weapon: lightsaber
    } 
    ...
}
```

Then in your template where you want to display the list, you just loop the results array and pull the obj from the entities map.

```
<li *ngFor="let id of (personPages$ | async)[1]?.results">
    {{(personEntities$ | async)[id]?.name }}
</li>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as I wrote in P.S. section I do not really want to use Map for all possible combinations I will be having ...

Comment: maybe a specific example of what you are trying to store would be more helpful to visualize your question/problem.